# New to Python/Kivy, trying to make a simple checkout system

Tags: python, kivy

I have an assignment for my compsci class that deals with making a simple GUI for checking out products. We just started Python/Kivy last week. I have an issue with getting my buttons to add to a total price.

What I want this program to do is when you click a button for a free burger, add 2 dollars to the total. When you click the button for a paid burger, add 1 dollar to the total. I am having trouble with getting them to add to the total.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.modules import inspector # For inspection.
from kivy.core.window import Window # For inspection.
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty
__app_package__ = 'edu.unl.cse.soft161.order'
__app__ = 'Order Meal'
__version__ = '0.1'
__flags__ = ['--bootstrap=sdl2', '--requirements=python2,kivy', '--orientation=landscape']


class OrderApp(App):
    total = NumericProperty(0)
    freeBurger = BooleanProperty(False)
    paidBurger = BooleanProperty(False)
    def build(self):
        inspector.create_inspector(Window, self) # For inspection (press control-e to toggle).
    def item(self, item):
        amount = NumericProperty(self.item)
        self.total = amount + self.total
    def service(self, service):
        amount = NumericProperty(self.service)
        self.total = self.total * amount

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = OrderApp()
    app.run()
```

KIVY APP HERE

```
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: button1
            text: 'Order Free Burger'
            value: 2
            on_press: app.item(self.value)

        Button:
            id: button2
            text: 'Order Paid Burger'
            value: 1
            on_press: app.item(self.value)
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Button:
            id: service1
            value: 1.2
            text: 'Good service'
            on_press: app.service(self.value)
        Button:
            id: service2
            value: 1.15
            text: 'Okay service'
        Button:
            id: service3
            value: 1.1
            text: 'Bad service'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'horizontal'
        Label:
            id: label1
            text: 'Meal Total:'
        Label:
            id: totalLabel
            text: str(app.total)
```

Comment: did my answer solve your problem? If not, let me know. If yes, please consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Instead of your

```
on_press: app.service(self.value)
```

in the .kv-file you can simply do

```
on_press: app.total += self.value
```

and you can safely delete the `item`-method in your Python file.

---

### Alternative solution:

Leave your .kv-file as is and change your `item`-method to read

```
def item(self, amount):
    self.total = amount + self.total  # or shorter: self.total += amount
```

---

### Explanation of your problem:

In your version of the `item`-method you are using `self.item` instead of the argument called `item`. But `self` refers to your object of type `OrderApp` and therefore `self.item` refers to its method called `item` - not the argument of this method which happens to have the same name. To reduce the possibility of confusion I have changed the argument's name to `amount` in my second solution.

Furthermore, it looks as if you were trying to define a `NumericProperty` inside the `item`-method. Don't do that ;) Such property declarations are only made at the class level (outside of any method). (And since you only want to use the argument `item` until the end of the `item`-method you don't need to save it permanently anyway.) The argument can be added to `self.total` without any transformation.

---

If you're facing similar problems again it might help to put some `print` statements in your code. This allows you to see in what state your variables right before the app crashes. An example of this technique is

```
def item(self, item):
    print "*" * 300  # prints 300 asterisks so you can find it quickly
    print self.item  # shows that self.item is a method and *not* the argument
    # ... more code ...
```

Have fun! :)